# Copy-on-write support in STL

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, stl, copy-on-write

I was just reading [a Wikipedia article on Copy-on-write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) (curious if there are any filesystems that support it), and was surprised by the following passage:

> COW is also used outside the kernel, in library, application and system code. The string class provided by the C++ standard library, for example, was specifically designed to allow copy-on-write implementations:

```
std::string x("Hello");

std::string y = x;  // x and y use the same buffer

y += ", World!";    // now y uses a different buffer
                    // x still uses the same old buffer
```

I didn't know that copy-on-write was every supported in STL. Is that true? Does it apply to other STL classes, e.g. `std::vector` or `std::array`? Which compilers support that optimization (in particular, I wonder about G++, Intel C++ compiler and Microsoft C++ compiler)?

Comment: Actually, `std::string` cannot be copy-on-write anymore, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16093748/256138).

Comment: The requirements places on `std::vector` and `std::array` rule out COW for those types. And requirements imposed on `std::string` in C++11 rule out COW for strings too.

Comment: One example of compiler supporting copy-on-write was Visual C++ 6.0. But not supported anymore since newer versions. As said before, is not supported anymore.

Comment: That's kind of sad :( I enjoyed greatly copy-on-write in Qt classes (it's called 'Implicit sharing' for some reason). What is the motivation for forbidding it?

Comment: @Septagram it generally performs worse in multithreaded code due to the additional locking required

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The string class provided by the C++ standard library, for example, was specifically designed to allow copy-on-write implementations

That is half-truth. Yes, it started design with COW in mind. But in the rush the public interface of std::string was messed up. Resulting it getting COW-hostile.  The problems were discovered after the standard published, and we're stuck with that ever since.  As stands currently `std::string` can not be thread-safely COW-ed and implementations in the wild don't do it.

If you want a COW-using string, get it from another library, like CString in MFC/ATL.

Answer (score 2):

gcc uses copy-by-reference for std::string.  As of version 4.8, it is still doing that for C++11, despite it [violating the standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199710/legality-of-cow-stdstring-implementation-in-c11).

See here:

- [Is std::string refcounted in GCC 4.x / C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520192/is-stdstring-refcounted-in-gcc-4-x-c11)
- [Turning off COW in GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12430598/86967)

Comment: How about these days?